# Where to store model attribute value translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, translation

I have a model Invoice with attribute payment_status. payment_status has fixed values unpayed|partial_payed|payed that I want to store the translations for in a locale-file.
I thougt it would be good to have it in the model local-file

```
de:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      payment_status: Zahlstatus
      payment_status_values:
        unpayed: offen
        partial_payed: teilgezahlt
        payed: ausgeglichen
```

now I can get the translated payment_status-value for the last invoice like this

```
I18n.t Invoice.last.payment_status , :scope => "activerecord.attributes.invoice.payment_status_values"
=> "offen"
```

to me it looks like typing sopes a lot, is there maybe a scoped method to get the translation or a better way to do this at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used the easy_enums plugin from marcel. The closest I found was: https://github.com/mschuerig/easy_enums/

Syntax is like this. Then you store only last part of the scope identifier.

```
  has_enum :shipping_mode, :default => :not_set, :fallback => :not_set do
    value :not_set
    value :address
    value :self_collect
    define_method(:localize) { I18n.t("models.payment.shipping_mode.#{self.id}") }
  end
```

Does that hit your goal?

Comment: are you sure it wasn't https://github.com/openteam/has_enum - easyenum has no has_enum method?

Comment: I found the one  http://rubygems.org/gems/easy_enum but after bundle and adding it to my Invoice class I get a NameError: uninitialized constant EasyEnum::ClassMethods::Enum